# Checkbox list label text via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a check box list which enables multi select. i need to get the label of each check  box instead of the value and do some work. if values are aaa &&& bbb i need to disable them (not allow user to check) and others i want to display as check able.

I have this piece of code written but doesn't work. I think I am missing something.

```
  $('#ddcl-ddlOutcomeList-ddw input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
      console.log($(this).html());
   });
```

ex:

```
  <div class="ui-dropdownchecklist-item ui-state-default" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="active" id="ddcl-ddlOutcomeList-i0" index="0" value="1444">
  <label for="ddcl-ddlOutcomeList-i0" class="ui-dropdownchecklist-text" style="cursor: default;">No answer</label>
  </div>

 <div class="ui-dropdownchecklist-item ui-state-default" style="white-space: nowrap;">
 <input type="checkbox" tabindex="1" class="active" id="ddcl-ddlOutcomeList-i1" index="0" value="1445">
 <label for="ddcl-ddlOutcomeList-i1" class="ui-dropdownchecklist-text" style="cursor: default;">No answer 2</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you post your html here or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @dfsq please check the below answer. i was able to get my work done with it.

Comment: dfsq answer is working... check it...

Comment: no it doesnt work for me. please help me with my below question

Comment: Hav u checked the fiddle link in his answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a way to do it by my self.

```
           $('#ddcl-ddlOutcomeList-ddw input:checkbox').each( function(e) {
        var  chkBoxVal=$("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") +"']").text();
        console.log(chkBoxVal);
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable checkboxes with `No answer` option you can try this:

```
$('label:contains("No answer")').prev(':checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PUJrQ/

Comment: how can i disable it this way ? what am i doing wrong here..             $('#ddcl-ddlOutcomeList-ddw input:checkbox').each( function(e) {
            var  chkBoxVal=$("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") +"']").text().toLowerCase();
            if (chkBoxVal == 'no answer' || chkBoxVal == 'left message' || chkBoxVal == 'engaged')
            {
               $(this).disabled();
                           console.log(chkBoxVal);
            }

Comment: You should use 'prop', not `attr`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="test"/>
<label for="test">THIS IS LABEL</label>
```

You can use `$("label[for='test']")`